Systemd mount works with username&password combo but not with credentials file
I just migrated an old server on a new machine. I'm now moving my old configuration , a key feature of my configuration, was to mount a remote directory on my server. It used to work perfectly but I'm having a small issue.
my systemd mount file on my old machine was:
[Unit]
  Description=mount Nas document folder
  Requires=awainetworkformount.service
  After=awainetworkformount.service

[Mount]
  What=//192.168.1.4/document
  Where=/mnt/NAS.Document
  Options=credentials=/etc/systemd.cred.Nas,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw
  Type=cifs

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target

My creds file being:
username=Pve1
password=password1234

And its permissions are set to 600.
But it doesn't work leaving me with this issue:
Nov 28 00:03:57 myserv systemd[1]: Mounting mount Nas document folder...
Nov 28 00:03:57 myserv mount[15457]: mount: /mnt/NAS.Document: cannot mount //192.168.1.4/document read-only.
Nov 28 00:03:57 myserv systemd[1]: mnt-NAS.Document.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Nov 28 00:03:57 myserv systemd[1]: mnt-NAS.Document.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 28 00:03:57 myserv systemd[1]: Failed to mount mount Nas document folder.

I found this temporary fix, which works but exposes my credentials, making me feel more exposed than I used to.
[Unit]
  Description=mount Nas document folder
  Requires=awainetworkformount.service
  After=awainetworkformount.service

[Mount]
  What=//192.168.1.4/document
  Where=/mnt/NAS.Document
  Options=username=Pve1,password=password1234,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw
  Type=cifs

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target


